# Dynamically update a single cell with contents from a fixed column reference, but from the current, active row

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, excel-formula

I am trying to have a certain header cell in excel dynamically update its contents depend on which row I am currently using, but with an address that has a fixed column. So the column reference for the header's contents will always be the same, however, I would like to have the row address change depending on the cell I am editing (i.e. the active cell).

```
  A                     B  
1 (dynamic header cell)
2  John                 likes to eat apples
3  Mary                 never smokes
4  Peter                tries too hard to be cool
5  David                loves madonna
```

So, If I click on cell A2 ("John"), I want the header cell (A1) to update with the contents of B2 ("likes to eat apples"), and similarly if I click on cell A4 ("Peter"), I want the same header cell (A1) to update with the contents of B4 ("tries too hard to be cool").

I have done some research, and I think perhaps I might use some combination of the cell function or the indirect function, but I cannot manage to get this to work.  I would prefer to use a simple formula, but if I need to do VBA, that is fine.

(If you suggest VBA, please include the whole function, because I don't know the language).

Can anyone help?

Comment: This would need to be in vba, in Worksheet_SelectionChange event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Scott Craner suggests, you'll need the "Worksheet_SelectionChange" event in VBA. Since you indicate not being familiar with VBA, I'll talk you through it. First, open the VBA editor by entering Alt+F11. In the VBA editor, enter Ctrl+R to open or jump to the project explorer (it's usually a pane on the left side of the window) and double-click the name of the sheet where you want your function. Now enter the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not(Intersect(ActiveCell, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing) Then
        Cells(1, 1).Value = Cells(Selection.Row, 2)
    End If
End Sub
```

The first line tells VBA it should execute the code whenever the selection changes. The second line checks if your selection is in column A. The third line actually does the trick: it takes the value from the second column of the selected row and puts this value in A1.

Comment: You may want to put in an intersect to make this only fire when it is column A that is selected.

Comment: I want this to fire whenever i activate ANY cell a particular row- but thank you. That was a thoughtful question. :)

Comment: In that case, you should remove the 2nd and 4th line in the code I suggestes

Comment: Sorry, I don't see any place in this code that allows me to specify the fixed column that will always be used to fill the dynamic cell regardless of row.  Where would that be entered in this code? For example, the source text in my example comes from column B always. After looking at your code, I think it is the 2, but that is strange to me, since excel uses letters to refer to columns.

Comment: Cells(Selection.Row, 2) is a reference to the 2nd column (i.e. column B) of the row on which a cell is selected

Comment: That worked like a charm!!! thank you so much to both of you NIH and Scott. I love this, it is magic!!!!  **A note to any other VBA clueless folks who might be reading this:** you need to save the excel file as macro-enabled. :)